# I can't color the text on click

Tags: javascript, html

When you click on a category, its name should turn red. But this only works for pre-rendered categories, and if you add a new one (it works with the input and 'add btn'), the event handler does not work, nothing happens with the text

```js
// * Adding active class for the cat
const addActiveClass = (elem) => {
  elem.classList.add("active");
};
// ! Removing active class
const removeActiveClass = (catArr) => {
  Array.from(catArr).forEach((elem) => {
    elem.classList.remove("active");
  });
};

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("categories__text")).forEach(
  (elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      removeActiveClass(document.getElementsByClassName
      ("categories__text"));
      addActiveClass(e.target);
    });
  }
);
console.log(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("categories__text")));
```

```html
<ul class="categories__list">
  <li class="categories__item">
    <p class="categories__text active">All</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from dynamically added elements not having the same event listeners as the ones initially present. The solution involves using event delegation, where you attach the event listener to a parent element and then verify if the clicked element matches your requirements. look here:

```
// Adding and removing active class
const toggleActiveClass = (elem) => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("categories__text")).forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.remove("active");
  });
  elem.classList.add("active");
};

// Here Goes Event delegation
document.querySelector('.categories__list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".categories__text")) {
    toggleActiveClass(e.target);
  }
});
```

This way, even elements added later will have the click functionality because the event listener is on the parent, not the individual elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am very grateful for the help. I sometimes see that event listening is added to an external block and then e.target is compared with the desired element. Could you tell me when to use this solution method? Sorry for the poor level of English, I use a translator to express my thoughts

Comment: No problem! Event Delegation is used when you want to attach the same event listener to many elements, including dynamically added ones. It improves performance and memory efficiency by using a single listener on a parent element. The clicked element is identified via event.target. It's particularly useful when elements are added or removed dynamically, as it eliminates the need to manage listeners for each element individually. This method is ideal for situations like your category addition feature.

Answer (score 1):

- Watch for click on the UL container
- `e.target` is the clicked element. Use `e.target.closest()` to get the clicked `.categories__text` if any.
- add the class, you don't need a separate function for that, seems an overkill

```js
document.querySelector('.categories__list')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
  
    const clicked = e.target.closest('.categories__text');
    if(clicked){
    
      // remove class from the previous item
      e.currentTarget.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');

      // add class to the clicked list item
      clicked.classList.add('active');
    }
  
  });

const addCategory = text => $list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <li class="categories__item">
    <p class="categories__text">${text}</p>
  </li>
`);
```

```css
.active{
  background:lightgray;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}
ul{
margin:0;padding:0;
}
p{
  margin:4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<ul id="$list" class="categories__list">
  <li class="categories__item">
    <p class="categories__text active">All</p>
  </li>
  <li class="categories__item">
    <p class="categories__text">Item 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="categories__item">
    <p class="categories__text">Item 2</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<input id="$input">
<button onclick="addCategory($input.value)">Add category</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I'm new to development, so I don't really understand what to put in a separate function and what not. But even I had doubts about creating a function for one line of code

Comment: @StepaFrolov if you create a function that doesn't add any new functionality to an existing function that means the function is useless, just use the original function

Comment: @StepaFrolov fixed the code to remove previously active item